# How can I get information about the user's browser via javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, web, httprequest

I am developing a website. I want to get as much as possible details about the end user who is viewing the website. I know some basic information like browser name, Operating system we can get it from http request. Want to know what else we can get.

Is it possible to get browser installed path?
Operating system logged user name? etc...

List of informations?

Comment: I'm kinda worried about your first 2 words: "Let's say"... So you aren't, but you still want to have that information.. Yes, I am worried now.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get the logged in user name or browser installed path (huge security risk!), but you can get information about the browser and operating system and so on in javascript via the browser's [navigator object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator)

The useragent property is a bit cryptic, so you might like to use a library to parse it for you such as [UAParser.js](http://faisalman.github.io/ua-parser-js/)